# Windows Phone sound spectrum

Tags: c#, xaml, xna, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to make a sound spectrum visualizer for Windows Phone. The thing is that the device is limited to a sampling rate of 16000 so the maximum Hz I can get is 8000 Hz.

Is there a way I can get up to 16,000 Hz or even the full 22 Khz like all the Android & iPhone apps do? Seeing as its just a spectrum the quality of it is not that important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the XNA APIs you're locked to 16kHz sample rate. You should try the native audio APIs.

See [Audio_recording_and_playback_options_in_Windows_Phone](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Audio_recording_and_playback_options_in_Windows_Phone) from the Nokia development site for your options.